# Reading android kernel messages

Tags: java, android, string, bufferedreader, filereader

I am trying to read /proc/kmsg live , but I don't know how to test whether I am successful or not.. I am trying to read it line by line in order to extract some useful info.

```
try {
            String line;
            kmsgBuf=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/kmsg"));

            while((line=kmsgBuf.readLine())!=null) {

                String output=kmsgBuf.toString();

                int indexFound=line.indexOf("MAC=");
                if(indexFound>-1){
                printme=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
                printme.setText("TRUE");
                }else if(indexFound<-1){                    
                printme=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
                printme.setText("FALSE");
                }
```

Comment: What happens when you run this? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Nothing , just an empty TextView

Comment: I just tried doing this manually on my unrooted device. I used `adb shell` and tried to run `cat /proc/kmsg` and it told me I don't have permission to do that. Maybe you need root?

Comment: The device is rooted , I can read the result if a start a process like Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c cat /proc/kmsg") ... The problem is that I cannot read anyting until the process is stopped... That's why I want to read directly from the file ... I want my program to remove the need of cat

Comment: "Rooting" only (potentially) affects a helper process, and not the code of your app itself.

Comment: Sure, but while cat is running you cannot extract data from the results.